# nx.get_node_attributes(G,attr) does not return anything (It is empty)

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, networkx, simulation

Here is my code:

```py
edge_node=5
access_node=1

e = range(edge_node) # [0 to 4]
n= range(edge_node,edge_node+(access_node)) # [4 to 5]
g = nx.Graph()

g.add_nodes_from(e, Type='Edge_node')
g.add_nodes_from(n, Type='Access_node')
allnodes = list(g.nodes()) # 5 nodes [0 to 5]

a = nx.get_node_attributes(g,'Type')
a.items()
```

The variable `a` is empty and I don't know why, please anyone can help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, If you could add the error your getting, it would help a lot in troubleshooting.

Comment: There is no error but variable a is empty... 
I want to print every node along with its type but I can't do so because variable a is empty

Comment: Your code works for me. `a` contains a dict of (node_id,Type) pairs. Maybe it's your version of networkx. Another way to get the node type for each node is to try `g.nodes(data="Type")` which should return a `NodeDataView` object that can be referenced just like the dict you expect from `get_node_attributes`